# How to handle failure in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I need to create a folder on my local drive when "something" changes in my domain. So in DDD fashion I need to raise an event and not let my domain create the folder.

My question is what if my event fails (i.e. the creation of the folder fails)?

Do I have to re-raise another command to undo the first change which I think is called a compensating command?

Also what if the compensating command fails? Now I have a domain change but the folder does not exist.

Comment: Do you necessarily have to make it event-driven?  Can the domain code call a service facade (which has an implementation that uses the file system) instead?  Then you'd just throw an exception on failure and the domain code would handle the exception.

Comment: Thanks David for the reply. I could but I am trying to get into the DDD way of doing things which talks about events being raised.

Comment: Also, with the DDD/Event driven approach if there are other sub systems that need to be notified, then creating an event handler for them should work more easily than the domain handling the logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you describe your proposed solution isn't really DDD; it's more CQRS (i.e. events & compensating commands) which I think is possibly over complicating the situation.

Do you really need to take a CQRS approach for this *scenario* which is intended for **asynchronous** operations? As in, what advantages are there for the folder being created in a separate transaction to the business logic being invoked and persisted? There is good reason for this approach when raising events that a query service handles, as the query service is likely to be on a separate physical machine, therefore requiring a RPC. Also, the event may require many de-normalised tables to be updated. So for performance it makes sense for this process to use the async eventing model. But for creating a local folder I'm not sure it does?

A possible approach

```
public class ApplicationService : IApplicationService
{
    private readonly IMyAggregateRepository _myAggregateRepository;
    private readonly IFolderCreationService _folderCreationService;

    public ApplicationService(IMyAggregateRepository myAggregateRepository, IFolderCreationService folderCreationService)
    {
        _myAggregateRepository = myAggregateRepository;
        _folderCreationService = folderCreationService;
    }

    public void SomeApplicationServiceMethod(Guid id)
    {
        using (IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.Create())
        {
            MyAggregate aggregate = _myAggregateRepository.GetById(id);

            aggregate.SomeMethod();

            _myAggregateRepository.Save(aggregate);

            _folderCreationService.CreateFolder();
        }
    }
}
```

Here, the changes are only committed to the database once all of the code within the unit of work's using statement completes without error.

Note that it isn't a *Domain Service*, or *Domain Entity* that invokes the folder service... it's the *Application Service*. I prefer keeping domain services focused on pure domain logic. It's the Application Service's job to orchestrate client calls to the domain, database and any other *infrastructure* services such as this folder service.

If you decide that there is good reason for this to use the event model, then what you said is correct. If the folder creation failed in the event handler you would have to issue a compensating command. You would need to ensure this handler cannot fail *by design* (by this I mean the entity in question is always in a state where this compensating command can be executed; and the state reverted). Having good unit tests that cover all scenarios will help. If there is a flaw in the design that allows this compensating command to fail, I guess you'd have to resort to manual intervention by sending an email/notification on failure.

P.S. Although not the point of the question, I'd really recommend not creating physical folders unless there really is a good reason. In my experience it just causes a head ache for deployments/machine upgrades and things. Obviously I don't know your reasons for doing so, but I'd really recommend using a document store/database for whatever you need to store instead.

Comment: David, thank you so much for the time and effort in this brilliant reply. I have been looking at CQRS over the last few months and I suppose I started seeing it as an architectural pattern for everything rather than for specific sub-domains :).  Unfortunately, I am migrating an existing app so we are stuck with folders but thanks once again for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If a file system folder is vital to your domain, I would implement the creation of folders as a domain service. That way, you would let the entity handle all business rules and logic and if the creation of a folder fails, your domain is not left in an invalid state.

Pass the service as a parameter to your method handling the logic (the double dispatch pattern).

Folder service example.

```
IFolderService
{
    CreateFolder(string path);
}
```

Entity example.

```
class MyEntity
{
    public void DoWork(IFolderService folderService, ...)
    {
        folderService.CreateFolder(...);

        // do work.
    }
}
```

After the work is done, you could raise domain events to notify sub systems.